# How to access user account's domain in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of administrator accounts on a machine.
So far I have this code below to show username

```
$obj_group = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators,group"
$members= @($obj_group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
foreach ($m in $members){
    echo ([ADSI]$m).PSBase.InvokeGet("Name")
}
```

But I also want to get a "domain" that these accounts belong to.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) for his help.</sup>

Try the following:

```
([ADSI] "WinNT://./Administrators,group").Members() |
  ForEach-Object { ([ADSI] $_).Path }
```

`.Path` returns the full directory-services URI (path) of the group members, which reflects the domain of origin, albeit by mere name, not as a FQDN (fully qualified domain name).

- Applying `.TrimStart('WinNT://')` on the result, as Santiago suggests, is a simple way to get rid of the protocol scheme.
- To extract just the domain name, use `(([ADSI] $_).Path -split '//?')[1]`

As for getting just the member *names*, your original code can be simplified to:

```
([ADSI] "WinNT://./Administrators,group").Members() |
  ForEach-Object { ([ADSI] $_).psbase.Name }
```

Note:

- While `.Invoke("Members")` can be used to invoke the `Members` method, regular method-invocation syntax works too (`.Members()`)
- The objects returned by `.Members()` must also be cast to `[ADSI]` in order for their members to be accessible (as shown in your question).
- Accessing the `.Name` property (the mere account name) requires use of the [intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.psbase` property, for reasons unknown to me.

  - By contrast, the `.Path` property - containing the account's full directory-services URI (path; e.g., `WinNT://SERVER1/Administrator`) - does not require use of `.psbase`

---

With the *exception of the `.Path` property, which must always be accessed directly*, **the awkwardness of `.psbase.someProperty` can be avoided with use of `.InvokeGet('someProperty')`** (as shown in your question, albeit without the need for `.psbase`)

This enables the following streamlined solutions to retrieve the `.Name` property values:

- With an `[adsi[]]` array cast - note the need for `@(...)` to force enumeration:

```
([adsi[]] @([adsi] "WinNT://./Administrators,group").Members()).InvokeGet('Name')
```

- Alternatively, as Santiago suggests, with the overload of the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) that accepts a type literal (`[adsi]`) as an argument, which similarly casts each member to `[adsi]`

```
([adsi] "WinNT://./Administrators,group").Members().ForEach([adsi]).InvokeGet('Name')
```